Flutter game on Steam Deck
I'm trying to get my Flutter-based game to run on the Steam Deck. It at least starts when I switch to "Proton Experimental", but it freezes right after the start and doesn't react to anything anymore, then. Here's my log:
======================

Proton: 1723129720 experimental-9.0-20240808
SteamGameId: 2695130
Command: ['/home/deck/devkit-game/EscapeTeamDebug/escape_team.exe']
Options: {'forcelgadd'}
depot: 0.20240806.97927
pressure-vessel: 0.20240806.0 scout
scripts: 0.20240806.0
sniper: 0.20240806.97927 sniper 0.20240806.97927
Kernel: Linux 5.13.0-valve37-1-neptune #1 SMP PREEMPT Thu, 17 Aug 2023 23:47:04 +0000 x86_64
Language: LC_ALL None, LC_MESSAGES None, LC_CTYPE None
System WINEDLLOVERRIDES: dxgi=n
Effective WINEDLLOVERRIDES: dxgi=n
Effective WINEDEBUG: +timestamp,+pid,+tid,+seh,+unwind,+threadname,+debugstr,+loaddll,+mscoree
======================
wine: using kernel write watches, use_kernel_writewatch 2.
wine: using kernel write watches, use_kernel_writewatch 2.
fsync: up and running.
pid 16721 != 16719, skipping destruction (fork without exec?)
wine: overriding CPU configuration, 8 logical CPUs, host CPUs 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7.
wine: overriding CPU configuration, 8 logical CPUs, host CPUs 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7.
wine: using kernel write watches, use_kernel_writewatch 2.
wine: overriding CPU configuration, 8 logical CPUs, host CPUs 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7.
13996.329:0030:0034:trace:seh:install_bpf Installing seccomp filters.
13996.329:0030:0034:trace:seh:check_bpf_jit_enable enabled 0x31.
13996.331:0030:0034:trace:loaddll:build_module Loaded L"C:\\windows\\system32\\wineboot.exe" at 0000000140000000: builtin
13996.332:0030:0034:trace:loaddll:build_module Loaded L"C:\\windows\\system32\\kernelbase.dll" at 00006FFFFFC10000: builtin
13996.332:0030:0034:trace:loaddll:build_module Loaded L"C:\\windows\\system32\\kernel32.dll" at 00006FFFFFEC0000: builtin
13996.334:0030:0034:trace:loaddll:build_module Loaded L"C:\\windows\\system32\\msvcrt.dll" at 00006FFFFFB00000: builtin
13996.335:0030:0034:trace:loaddll:build_module Loaded L"C:\\windows\\system32\\ucrtbase.dll" at 00006FFFFF9E0000: builtin
13996.335:0030:0034:trace:loaddll:build_module Loaded L"C:\\windows\\system32\\sechost.dll" at 00006FFFFFAC0000: builtin
13996.335:0030:0034:trace:loaddll:build_module Loaded L"C:\\windows\\system32\\advapi32.dll" at 00006FFFFFBB0000: builtin
13996.335:0030:0034:trace:loaddll:build_module Loaded L"C:\\windows\\system32\\ws2_32.dll" at 00006FFFFF9A0000: builtin
wine: using kernel write watches, use_kernel_writewatch 2.
wine: overriding CPU configuration, 8 logical CPUs, host CPUs 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7.
13996.376:0038:003c:trace:seh:sigsys_handler SIGSYS, rax 0xffff, rip 0x600000000005.
13996.376:0038:003c:trace:seh:install_bpf Seccomp filters already installed.
13996.376:0038:003c:trace:loaddll:build_module Loaded L"C:\\windows\\system32\\services.exe" at 0000000140000000: builtin
13996.377:0038:003c:trace:loaddll:build_module Loaded L"C:\\windows\\system32\\kernelbase.dll" at 00006FFFFFC10000: builtin
13996.377:0038:003c:trace:loaddll:build_module Loaded L"C:\\windows\\system32\\kernel32.dll" at 00006FFFFFEC0000: builtin
13996.379:0038:003c:trace:loaddll:build_module Loaded L"C:\\windows\\system32\\msvcrt.dll" at 00006FFFFFB00000: builtin
13996.379:0038:003c:trace:loaddll:build_module Loaded L"C:\\windows\\system32\\ucrtbase.dll" at 00006FFFFF9E0000: builtin
13996.379:0038:003c:trace:loaddll:build_module Loaded L"C:\\windows\\system32\\sechost.dll" at 00006FFFFFAC0000: builtin
13996.379:0038:003c:trace:loaddll:build_module Loaded L"C:\\windows\\system32\\advapi32.dll" at 00006FFFFFBB0000: builtin
13996.379:0038:003c:trace:loaddll:build_module Loaded L"C:\\windows\\system32\\rpcrt4.dll" at 00006FFFFF910000: builtin
13996.380:0038:003c:trace:loaddll:build_module Loaded L"C:\\windows\\system32\\setupapi.dll" at 00006FFFFF890000: builtin
13996.380:0038:003c:trace:loaddll:build_module Loaded L"C:\\windows\\system32\\userenv.dll" at 00006FFFFF870000: builtin
13996.389:0038:0040:warn:threadname:NtSetInformationThread Thread renamed to L"wine_rpcrt4_server"
wine: using kernel write watches, use_kernel_writewatch 2.
wine: overriding CPU configuration, 8 logical CPUs, host CPUs 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7.
13996.412:0044:0048:trace:seh:sigsys_handler SIGSYS, rax 0xffff, rip 0x600000000005.
13996.412:0044:0048:trace:seh:install_bpf Seccomp filters already installed.
13996.413:0044:0048:trace:loaddll:build_module Loaded L"C:\\windows\\system32\\winedevice.exe" at 0000000140000000: builtin
13996.414:0044:0048:trace:loaddll:build_module Loaded L"C:\\windows\\system32\\kernelbase.dll" at 00006FFFFFC10000: builtin
13996.414:0044:0048:trace:loaddll:build_module Loaded L"C:\\windows\\system32\\kernel32.dll" at 00006FFFFFEC0000: builtin
13996.415:0044:0048:trace:loaddll:build_module Loaded L"C:\\windows\\system32\\msvcrt.dll" at 00006FFFFFB00000: builtin
13996.416:0044:0048:trace:loaddll:build_module Loaded L"C:\\windows\\system32\\ucrtbase.dll" at 00006FFFFF9E0000: builtin
13996.416:0044:0048:trace:loaddll:build_module Loaded L"C:\\windows\\system32\\sechost.dll" at 00006FFFFFAC0000: builtin
13996.416:0044:0048:trace:loaddll:build_module Loaded L"C:\\windows\\system32\\advapi32.dll" at 00006FFFFFBB0000: builtin
13996.416:0044:0048:trace:loaddll:build_module Loaded L"C:\\windows\\system32\\ntoskrnl.exe" at 00006FFFFF800000: builtin
13996.420:0044:0048:trace:loaddll:build_module Loaded L"C:\\windows\\system32\\rpcrt4.dll" at 00006FFFFF910000: builtin
13996.422:0038:004c:warn:threadname:NtSetInformationThread Thread renamed to L"wine_rpcrt4_io"
13996.423:0038:0050:warn:threadname:NtSetInformationThread Thread renamed to L"wine_threadpool_worker"
13996.425:0044:0058:warn:threadname:NtSetInformationThread Thread renamed to L"wine_sechost_service"
13996.426:0038:005c:warn:threadname:NtSetInformationThread Thread renamed to L"wine_rpcrt4_io"
13996.428:0044:0054:trace:loaddll:build_module Loaded L"C:\\windows\\system32\\drivers\\mountmgr.sys" at 00006FFFFF7E0000: builtin
13996.432:0044:0054:trace:loaddll:build_module Loaded L"C:\\windows\\system32\\setupapi.dll" at 00006FFFFF890000: builtin
13996.436:0044:0060:trace:loaddll:build_module Loaded L"C:\\windows\\system32\\win32u.dll" at 00006FFFFF540000: builtin
13996.436:0044:0060:trace:loaddll:build_module Loaded L"C:\\windows\\system32\\gdi32.dll" at 00006FFFFF590000: builtin
13996.437:0044:0060:trace:loaddll:build_module Loaded L"C:\\windows\\system32\\user32.dll" at 00006FFFFF620000: builtin
wine: using kernel write watches, use_kernel_writewatch 2.
wine: overriding CPU configuration, 8 logical CPUs, host CPUs 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7.
13996.452:006c:0070:trace:seh:sigsys_handler SIGSYS, rax 0xffff, rip 0x600000000005.
13996.452:006c:0070:trace:seh:install_bpf Seccomp filters already installed.
13996.453:006c:0070:trace:loaddll:build_module Loaded L"C:\\windows\\system32\\winedevice.exe" at 0000000140000000: builtin
13996.453:006c:0070:trace:loaddll:build_module Loaded L"C:\\windows\\system32\\kernelbase.dll" at 00006FFFFFC10000: builtin
13996.453:006c:0070:trace:loaddll:build_module Loaded L"C:\\windows\\system32\\kernel32.dll" at 00006FFFFFEC0000: builtin
13996.455:006c:0070:trace:loaddll:build_module Loaded L"C:\\windows\\system32\\msvcrt.dll" at 00006FFFFFB00000: builtin
13996.455:006c:0070:trace:loaddll:build_module Loaded L"C:\\windows\\system32\\ucrtbase.dll" at 00006FFFFF9E0000: builtin
13996.455:006c:0070:trace:loaddll:build_module Loaded L"C:\\windows\\system32\\sechost.dll" at 00006FFFFFAC0000: builtin
13996.455:006c:0070:trace:loaddll:build_module Loaded L"C:\\windows\\system32\\advapi32.dll" at 00006FFFFFBB0000: builtin
13996.455:006c:0070:trace:loaddll:build_module Loaded L"C:\\windows\\system32\\ntoskrnl.exe" at 00006FFFFF800000: builtin
13996.459:006c:0070:trace:loaddll:build_module Loaded L"C:\\windows\\system32\\rpcrt4.dll" at 00006FFFFF910000: builtin
13996.461:0038:0074:warn:threadname:NtSetInformationThread Thread renamed to L"wine_rpcrt4_io"
13996.464:006c:007c:warn:threadname:NtSetInformationThread Thread renamed to L"wine_sechost_service"
13996.466:006c:0078:trace:loaddll:build_module Loaded L"C:\\windows\\system32\\drivers\\wineusb.sys" at 00006FFFFF520000: builtin
13996.467:006c:0078:trace:loaddll:build_module Loaded L"C:\\windows\\system32\\setupapi.dll" at 00006FFFFF890000: builtin
13996.475:006c:0078:trace:loaddll:build_module Loaded L"C:\\windows\\system32\\drivers\\hidparse.sys" at 00006FFFFF4D0000: builtin
13996.475:006c:0078:trace:loaddll:build_module Loaded L"C:\\windows\\system32\\drivers\\winebus.sys" at 00006FFFFF500000: builtin
13996.475:006c:0080:fixme:wineusb:add_usb_device Interface 1 has 6 alternate settings; using the first one.
13996.476:006c:0080:fixme:wineusb:query_id Unhandled ID query type 0x5.
13996.478:006c:0078:fixme:hid:handle_IRP_MN_QUERY_ID Unhandled type 00000005
13996.479:006c:0080:fixme:wineusb:query_id Unhandled ID query type 0x5.
13996.482:006c:0080:fixme:wineusb:query_id Unhandled ID query type 0x5.
13996.483:006c:0078:trace:loaddll:build_module Loaded L"C:\\windows\\system32\\win32u.dll" at 00006FFFFF540000: builtin
13996.483:006c:0078:trace:loaddll:build_module Loaded L"C:\\windows\\system32\\gdi32.dll" at 00006FFFFF590000: builtin
13996.483:006c:0078:trace:loaddll:build_module Loaded L"C:\\windows\\system32\\user32.dll" at 00006FFFFF620000: builtin
13996.483:006c:0078:trace:loaddll:build_module Loaded L"C:\\windows\\system32\\drivers\\hidclass.sys" at 00006FFFFF490000: builtin
13996.483:006c:0078:trace:loaddll:build_module Loaded L"C:\\windows\\system32\\drivers\\winehid.sys" at 00006FFFFF4B0000: builtin
13996.485:006c:0080:fixme:wineusb:query_id Unhandled ID query type 0x5.
13996.487:006c:0080:fixme:wineusb:query_id Unhandled ID query type 0x5.
13996.490:006c:0080:fixme:wineusb:query_id Unhandled ID query type 0x5.
13996.493:006c:0080:fixme:wineusb:query_id Unhandled ID query type 0x5.
13996.495:006c:0080:fixme:wineusb:query_id Unhandled ID query type 0x5.
13996.498:006c:0080:fixme:wineusb:query_id Unhandled ID query type 0x5.
13996.500:006c:0080:fixme:wineusb:query_id Unhandled ID query type 0x5.
13996.502:006c:0080:fixme:wineusb:query_id Unhandled ID query type 0x5.
13996.716:0044:0060:trace:loaddll:build_module Loaded L"C:\\windows\\system32\\imm32.dll" at 00006FFFFF460000: builtin
13996.726:006c:0078:trace:loaddll:build_module Loaded L"C:\\windows\\system32\\imm32.dll" at 00006FFFFF460000: builtin
13996.727:006c:0078:fixme:hid:handle_IRP_MN_QUERY_ID Unhandled type 00000005
13996.730:006c:0078:trace:seh:dispatch_exception code=6ba flags=0 addr=00006FFFFFC1CF07 ip=6fffffc1cf07
13996.730:006c:0078:warn:seh:dispatch_exception RPC_S_SERVER_UNAVAILABLE exception (code=6ba) raised
13996.730:006c:0078:trace:seh:dispatch_exception  rax=0000000000a2d7e0 rbx=0000000000a2dac8 rcx=0000000000a2d7e0 rdx=0000000000000000
13996.730:006c:0078:trace:seh:dispatch_exception  rsi=00000000000000cc rdi=00000000007f5aa0 rbp=0000000000a2d8b0 rsp=0000000000a2d7c0
13996.730:006c:0078:trace:seh:dispatch_exception   r8=0000000000000000  r9=0000000000000000 r10=00000000007fd220 r11=0000000000000016
13996.730:006c:0078:trace:seh:dispatch_exception  r12=0000000000a2dac8 r13=0000000000e31220 r14=0000000000e31220 r15=00000000000000b8
13996.730:006c:0078:trace:seh:call_vectored_handlers calling handler at 00006FFFFF825A00 code=6ba flags=0
13996.730:006c:0078:trace:seh:call_vectored_handlers handler at 00006FFFFF825A00 returned 0
13996.730:006c:0078:trace:unwind:RtlVirtualUnwind type 1 rip 6fffffc1cf07 rsp a2d7c0
13996.730:006c:0078:trace:unwind:dump_unwind_info **** func ce98-cf0f
13996.730:006c:0078:trace:unwind:dump_unwind_info unwind info at 00006FFFFFCC9CA8 flags 0 prolog 0xf bytes function 00006FFFFFC1CE98-00006FFFFFC1CF0F
13996.730:006c:0078:trace:unwind:dump_unwind_info     0xf: subq $0xc8,%rsp
13996.730:006c:0078:trace:unwind:RtlVirtualUnwind inside epilog.
13996.730:006c:0078:trace:unwind:RtlVirtualUnwind type 1 rip 6fffff9407e6 rsp a2d890
13996.730:006c:0078:trace:unwind:dump_unwind_info **** func 307d0-3081b
13996.730:006c:0078:trace:unwind:dump_unwind_info unwind info at 00006FFFFF98582C flags 0 prolog 0x8 bytes function 00006FFFFF9407D0-00006FFFFF94081B
13996.730:006c:0078:trace:unwind:dump_unwind_info     frame register rbp offset 0x0(%rsp)
13996.730:006c:0078:trace:unwind:dump_unwind_info     0x8: subq $0x20,%rsp
13996.730:006c:0078:trace:unwind:dump_unwind_info     0x4: leaq 0x0(%rsp),rbp
13996.730:006c:0078:trace:unwind:dump_unwind_info     0x1: pushq %rbp
13996.730:006c:0078:trace:unwind:RtlVirtualUnwind type 1 rip 6fffff92d086 rsp a2d8c0
13996.730:006c:0078:trace:unwind:dump_unwind_info **** func 1cff0-1d087
13996.730:006c:0078:trace:unwind:dump_unwind_info unwind info at 00006FFFFF982F9C flags 0 prolog 0xd bytes function 00006FFFFF92CFF0-00006FFFFF92D087
13996.730:006c:0078:trace:unwind:dump_unwind_info     frame register rbp offset 0x40(%rsp)
13996.730:006c:0078:trace:unwind:dump_unwind_info     0xd: leaq 0x40(%rsp),rbp
13996.730:006c:0078:trace:unwind:dump_unwind_info     0x8: subq $0x48,%rsp
13996.730:006c:0078:trace:unwind:dump_unwind_info     0x4: pushq %rbx
13996.730:006c:0078:trace:unwind:dump_unwind_info     0x3: pushq %rsi
13996.730:006c:0078:trace:unwind:dump_unwind_info     0x2: pushq %rdi
13996.730:006c:0078:trace:unwind:dump_unwind_info     0x1: pushq %rbp
13996.730:006c:0078:trace:unwind:RtlVirtualUnwind type 1 rip 6fffff824a72 rsp a2d930
13996.730:006c:0078:trace:unwind:dump_unwind_info **** func 24980-24b89
13996.730:006c:0078:trace:unwind:dump_unwind_info unwind info at 00006FFFFF843A14 flags 0 prolog 0x17 bytes function 00006FFFFF824980-00006FFFFF824B89
13996.730:006c:0078:trace:unwind:dump_unwind_info     frame register rbp offset 0x80(%rsp)
13996.730:006c:0078:trace:unwind:dump_unwind_info     0x17: leaq 0x80(%rsp),rbp
13996.730:006c:0078:trace:unwind:dump_unwind_info     0xf: subq $0x338,%rsp
13996.730:006c:0078:trace:unwind:dump_unwind_info     0x8: pushq %rbx
13996.730:006c:0078:trace:unwind:dump_unwind_info     0x7: pushq %rsi
13996.730:006c:0078:trace:unwind:dump_unwind_info     0x6: pushq %rdi
13996.730:006c:0078:trace:unwind:dump_unwind_info     0x5: pushq %r12
13996.730:006c:0078:trace:unwind:dump_unwind_info     0x3: pushq %r13
13996.730:006c:0078:trace:unwind:dump_unwind_info     0x1: pushq %rbp
13996.730:006c:0078:trace:seh:call_stack_handlers found wine frame 0000000000A2D9A0 rsp 0000000000A2DCA0 handler 00006FFFFF81EB00
13996.730:006c:0078:trace:seh:call_teb_handler calling TEB handler 00006FFFFF81EB00 (rec=0000000000A2D7E0, frame=0000000000A2D9A0 context=0000000000A2CD10, dispatch=0000000000A2CBE0)
13996.730:006c:0078:trace:seh:call_teb_handler handler at 00006FFFFF81EB00 returned 1
13996.730:006c:0078:trace:unwind:RtlVirtualUnwind type 1 rip 6fffff825430 rsp a2dca0
13996.730:006c:0078:trace:unwind:dump_unwind_info **** func 25360-25441
13996.730:006c:0078:trace:unwind:dump_unwind_info unwind info at 00006FFFFF843410 flags 0 prolog 0x11 bytes function 00006FFFFF825360-00006FFFFF825441
13996.730:006c:0078:trace:unwind:dump_unwind_info     frame register rbp offset 0x80(%rsp)
13996.730:006c:0078:trace:unwind:dump_unwind_info     0x11: leaq 0x80(%rsp),rbp
13996.730:006c:0078:trace:unwind:dump_unwind_info     0x9: subq $0x168,%rsp
13996.730:006c:0078:trace:unwind:dump_unwind_info     0x2: pushq %rbx
13996.730:006c:0078:trace:unwind:dump_unwind_info     0x1: pushq %rbp
13996.730:006c:0078:trace:seh:call_stack_handlers found wine frame 0000000000A2DCD0 rsp 0000000000A2DE20 handler 00006FFFFF81EDB0
13996.730:006c:0078:trace:seh:call_teb_handler calling TEB handler 00006FFFFF81EDB0 (rec=0000000000A2D7E0, frame=0000000000A2DCD0 context=0000000000A2CD10, dispatch=0000000000A2CBE0)
13996.730:006c:0078:trace:unwind:RtlUnwindEx code=6ba flags=2 end_frame=0000000000A2DCD0 target_ip=00006FFFFF80D98A rip=00006ffffff73485
13996.730:006c:0078:trace:unwind:RtlUnwindEx  rax=000000007ffb0000 rbx=0000000000a2d9a0 rcx=0000000000a2c5d0 rdx=00006fffff80d98a
13996.730:006c:0078:trace:unwind:RtlUnwindEx  rsi=0000000000a2c080 rdi=0000000000a2d7e0 rbp=0000000000a2bf90 rsp=0000000000a2bf10
13996.730:006c:0078:trace:unwind:RtlUnwindEx   r8=0000000000a2d7e0  r9=00006fffff8259d0 r10=0000000000a2c9e0 r11=0000000000029030
13996.730:006c:0078:trace:unwind:RtlUnwindEx  r12=0000000000a2d7e0 r13=0000000000a2c5d0 r14=0000000000a2dcd0 r15=00006ffffffae2c0
13996.730:006c:0078:trace:unwind:RtlVirtualUnwind type 2 rip 6ffffff73485 rsp a2bf10
13996.730:006c:0078:trace:unwind:dump_unwind_info **** func 33430-33b98
13996.730:006c:0078:trace:unwind:dump_unwind_info unwind info at 00006FFFFFFD7E10 flags 0 prolog 0x1b bytes function 00006FFFFFF73430-00006FFFFFF73B98
13996.730:006c:0078:trace:unwind:dump_unwind_info     frame register rbp offset 0x80(%rsp)
13996.730:006c:0078:trace:unwind:dump_unwind_info     0x1b: leaq 0x80(%rsp),rbp
13996.730:006c:0078:trace:unwind:dump_unwind_info     0x13: subq $0x648,%rsp
13996.730:006c:0078:trace:unwind:dump_unwind_info     0xc: pushq %rbx
13996.730:006c:0078:trace:unwind:dump_unwind_info     0xb: pushq %rsi
13996.730:006c:0078:trace:unwind:dump_unwind_info     0xa: pushq %rdi
13996.730:006c:0078:trace:unwind:dump_unwind_info     0x9: pushq %r12
13996.730:006c:0078:trace:unwind:dump_unwind_info     0x7: pushq %r13
13996.730:006c:0078:trace:unwind:dump_unwind_info     0x5: pushq %r14
13996.730:006c:0078:trace:unwind:dump_unwind_info     0x3: pushq %r15
13996.730:006c:0078:trace:unwind:dump_unwind_info     0x1: pushq %rbp
13996.730:006c:0078:trace:unwind:RtlVirtualUnwind type 2 rip 6ffffff73417 rsp a2c5a0
13996.730:006c:0078:trace:unwind:dump_unwind_info **** func 333f0-33421
13996.730:006c:0078:trace:unwind:dump_unwind_info unwind info at 00006FFFFFFD7E2C flags 0 prolog 0x10 bytes function 00006FFFFFF733F0-00006FFFFFF73421
13996.730:006c:0078:trace:unwind:dump_unwind_info     frame register rbp offset 0x80(%rsp)
13996.730:006c:0078:trace:unwind:dump_unwind_info     0x10: leaq 0x80(%rsp),rbp
13996.730:006c:0078:trace:unwind:dump_unwind_info     0x8: subq $0x500,%rsp
13996.730:006c:0078:trace:unwind:dump_unwind_info     0x1: pushq %rbp
13996.730:006c:0078:trace:unwind:RtlVirtualUnwind type 2 rip 6fffff80d98a rsp a2cab0
13996.730:006c:0078:trace:unwind:dump_unwind_info **** func d970-d98c
13996.730:006c:0078:trace:unwind:dump_unwind_info unwind info at 00006FFFFF843AF8 flags 0 prolog 0x8 bytes function 00006FFFFF80D970-00006FFFFF80D98C
13996.730:006c:0078:trace:unwind:dump_unwind_info     frame register rbp offset 0x0(%rsp)
13996.730:006c:0078:trace:unwind:dump_unwind_info     0x8: subq $0x20,%rsp
13996.730:006c:0078:trace:unwind:dump_unwind_info     0x4: leaq 0x0(%rsp),rbp
13996.730:006c:0078:trace:unwind:dump_unwind_info     0x1: pushq %rbp
13996.730:006c:0078:trace:unwind:RtlVirtualUnwind type 2 rip 6fffff8259cd rsp a2cae0
13996.730:006c:0078:trace:unwind:dump_unwind_info **** func 259a0-259ce
13996.730:006c:0078:trace:unwind:dump_unwind_info unwind info at 00006FFFFF843B04 flags 0 prolog 0x8 bytes function 00006FFFFF8259A0-00006FFFFF8259CE
13996.730:006c:0078:trace:unwind:dump_unwind_info     frame register rbp offset 0x0(%rsp)
13996.730:006c:0078:trace:unwind:dump_unwind_info     0x8: subq $0x20,%rsp
13996.730:006c:0078:trace:unwind:dump_unwind_info     0x4: leaq 0x0(%rsp),rbp
13996.730:006c:0078:trace:unwind:dump_unwind_info     0x1: pushq %rbp
13996.730:006c:0078:trace:unwind:RtlVirtualUnwind type 2 rip 6fffff81ee08 rsp a2cb10
13996.730:006c:0078:trace:unwind:dump_unwind_info **** func 1edb0-1ee09
13996.730:006c:0078:trace:unwind:dump_unwind_info unwind info at 00006FFFFF843B1C flags 0 prolog 0x10 bytes function 00006FFFFF81EDB0-00006FFFFF81EE09
13996.730:006c:0078:trace:unwind:dump_unwind_info     frame register rbp offset 0x30(%rsp)
13996.730:006c:0078:trace:unwind:dump_unwind_info     0x10: leaq 0x30(%rsp),rbp
13996.730:006c:0078:trace:unwind:dump_unwind_info     0xb: subq $0x38,%rsp
13996.730:006c:0078:trace:unwind:dump_unwind_info     0x7: pushq %r12
13996.730:006c:0078:trace:unwind:dump_unwind_info     0x5: pushq %r13
13996.730:006c:0078:trace:unwind:dump_unwind_info     0x3: pushq %r14
13996.730:006c:0078:trace:unwind:dump_unwind_info     0x1: pushq %rbp
13996.730:006c:0078:trace:unwind:RtlVirtualUnwind type 2 rip 6ffffff81d5d rsp a2cb70
13996.730:006c:0078:trace:unwind:dump_unwind_info **** func 41a90-41f81
13996.730:006c:0078:trace:unwind:dump_unwind_info unwind info at 00006FFFFFFD7DA8 flags 0 prolog 0x1b bytes function 00006FFFFFF81A90-00006FFFFFF81F81
13996.730:006c:0078:trace:unwind:dump_unwind_info     frame register rbp offset 0x80(%rsp)
13996.730:006c:0078:trace:unwind:dump_unwind_info     0x1b: leaq 0x80(%rsp),rbp
13996.730:006c:0078:trace:unwind:dump_unwind_info     0x13: subq $0x678,%rsp
13996.730:006c:0078:trace:unwind:dump_unwind_info     0xc: pushq %rbx
13996.730:006c:0078:trace:unwind:dump_unwind_info     0xb: pushq %rsi
13996.730:006c:0078:trace:unwind:dump_unwind_info     0xa: pushq %rdi
13996.730:006c:0078:trace:unwind:dump_unwind_info     0x9: pushq %r12
13996.730:006c:0078:trace:unwind:dump_unwind_info     0x7: pushq %r13
13996.730:006c:0078:trace:unwind:dump_unwind_info     0x5: pushq %r14
13996.730:006c:0078:trace:unwind:dump_unwind_info     0x3: pushq %r15
13996.730:006c:0078:trace:unwind:dump_unwind_info     0x1: pushq %rbp
13996.730:006c:0078:trace:unwind:RtlVirtualUnwind type 2 rip 6ffffff84507 rsp a2d230
13996.730:006c:0078:trace:unwind:dump_unwind_info **** func 441e0-447dc
13996.730:006c:0078:trace:unwind:dump_unwind_info unwind info at 00006FFFFFFD7DC4 flags 0 prolog 0x15 bytes function 00006FFFFFF841E0-00006FFFFFF847DC
13996.730:006c:0078:trace:unwind:dump_unwind_info     frame register rbp offset 0x40(%rsp)
13996.730:006c:0078:trace:unwind:dump_unwind_info     0x15: leaq 0x40(%rsp),rbp
13996.730:006c:0078:trace:unwind:dump_unwind_info     0x10: subq $0x48,%rsp
13996.730:006c:0078:trace:unwind:dump_unwind_info     0xc: pushq %rbx
13996.730:006c:0078:trace:unwind:dump_unwind_info     0xb: pushq %rsi
13996.730:006c:0078:trace:unwind:dump_unwind_info     0xa: pushq %rdi
13996.730:006c:0078:trace:unwind:dump_unwind_info     0x9: pushq %r12
13996.730:006c:0078:trace:unwind:dump_unwind_info     0x7: pushq %r13
13996.730:006c:0078:trace:unwind:dump_unwind_info     0x5: pushq %r14
13996.730:006c:0078:trace:unwind:dump_unwind_info     0x3: pushq %r15
13996.730:006c:0078:trace:unwind:dump_unwind_info     0x1: pushq %rbp
13996.730:006c:0078:trace:unwind:RtlVirtualUnwind type 2 rip 6ffffff4f3db rsp a2d2c0
13996.730:006c:0078:trace:unwind:dump_unwind_info **** func f36c-f3e8
13996.730:006c:0078:trace:unwind:dump_unwind_info unwind info at 00006FFFFFFD7CDC flags 0 prolog 0x7 bytes function 00006FFFFFF4F36C-00006FFFFFF4F3E8
13996.730:006c:0078:trace:unwind:dump_unwind_info     0x7: subq $0x4f8,%rsp
13996.730:006c:0078:trace:unwind:RtlVirtualUnwind type 2 rip 6fffffc1cf07 rsp a2d7c0
13996.730:006c:0078:trace:unwind:dump_unwind_info **** func ce98-cf0f
13996.730:006c:0078:trace:unwind:dump_unwind_info unwind info at 00006FFFFFCC9CA8 flags 0 prolog 0xf bytes function 00006FFFFFC1CE98-00006FFFFFC1CF0F
13996.730:006c:0078:trace:unwind:dump_unwind_info     0xf: subq $0xc8,%rsp
13996.730:006c:0078:trace:unwind:RtlVirtualUnwind inside epilog.
13996.730:006c:0078:trace:unwind:RtlVirtualUnwind type 2 rip 6fffff9407e6 rsp a2d890
13996.730:006c:0078:trace:unwind:dump_unwind_info **** func 307d0-3081b
13996.730:006c:0078:trace:unwind:dump_unwind_info unwind info at 00006FFFFF98582C flags 0 prolog 0x8 bytes function 00006FFFFF9407D0-00006FFFFF94081B
13996.730:006c:0078:trace:unwind:dump_unwind_info     frame register rbp offset 0x0(%rsp)
13996.730:006c:0078:trace:unwind:dump_unwind_info     0x8: subq $0x20,%rsp
13996.730:006c:0078:trace:unwind:dump_unwind_info     0x4: leaq 0x0(%rsp),rbp
13996.730:006c:0078:trace:unwind:dump_unwind_info     0x1: pushq %rbp
13996.730:006c:0078:trace:unwind:RtlVirtualUnwind type 2 rip 6fffff92d086 rsp a2d8c0
13996.730:006c:0078:trace:unwind:dump_unwind_info **** func 1cff0-1d087
13996.730:006c:0078:trace:unwind:dump_unwind_info unwind info at 00006FFFFF982F9C flags 0 prolog 0xd bytes function 00006FFFFF92CFF0-00006FFFFF92D087
13996.730:006c:0078:trace:unwind:dump_unwind_info     frame register rbp offset 0x40(%rsp)
13996.730:006c:0078:trace:unwind:dump_unwind_info     0xd: leaq 0x40(%rsp),rbp
13996.730:006c:0078:trace:unwind:dump_unwind_info     0x8: subq $0x48,%rsp
13996.730:006c:0078:trace:unwind:dump_unwind_info     0x4: pushq %rbx
13996.730:006c:0078:trace:unwind:dump_unwind_info     0x3: pushq %rsi
13996.730:006c:0078:trace:unwind:dump_unwind_info     0x2: pushq %rdi
13996.730:006c:0078:trace:unwind:dump_unwind_info     0x1: pushq %rbp
13996.730:006c:0078:trace:unwind:RtlVirtualUnwind type 2 rip 6fffff824a72 rsp a2d930
13996.730:006c:0078:trace:unwind:dump_unwind_info **** func 24980-24b89
13996.730:006c:0078:trace:unwind:dump_unwind_info unwind info at 00006FFFFF843A14 flags 0 prolog 0x17 bytes function 00006FFFFF824980-00006FFFFF824B89
13996.730:006c:0078:trace:unwind:dump_unwind_info     frame register rbp offset 0x80(%rsp)
13996.730:006c:0078:trace:unwind:dump_unwind_info     0x17: leaq 0x80(%rsp),rbp
13996.730:006c:0078:trace:unwind:dump_unwind_info     0xf: subq $0x338,%rsp
13996.730:006c:0078:trace:unwind:dump_unwind_info     0x8: pushq %rbx
13996.730:006c:0078:trace:unwind:dump_unwind_info     0x7: pushq %rsi
13996.730:006c:0078:trace:unwind:dump_unwind_info     0x6: pushq %rdi
13996.730:006c:0078:trace:unwind:dump_unwind_info     0x5: pushq %r12
13996.730:006c:0078:trace:unwind:dump_unwind_info     0x3: pushq %r13
13996.730:006c:0078:trace:unwind:dump_unwind_info     0x1: pushq %rbp
13996.730:006c:0078:trace:unwind:RtlUnwindEx found builtin frame 0000000000A2D9A0 handler 00006FFFFF81EB00
13996.730:006c:0078:trace:unwind:call_teb_unwind_handler calling TEB handler 00006FFFFF81EB00 (rec=0000000000A2D7E0, frame=0000000000A2D9A0 context=0000000000A2C5D0, dispatch=0000000000A2BF90)
13996.730:006c:0078:trace:unwind:call_teb_unwind_handler handler at 00006FFFFF81EB00 returned 1
13996.730:006c:0078:trace:unwind:RtlVirtualUnwind type 2 rip 6fffff825430 rsp a2dca0
13996.730:006c:0078:trace:unwind:dump_unwind_info **** func 25360-25441
13996.730:006c:0078:trace:unwind:dump_unwind_info unwind info at 00006FFFFF843410 flags 0 prolog 0x11 bytes function 00006FFFFF825360-00006FFFFF825441
13996.730:006c:0078:trace:unwind:dump_unwind_info     frame register rbp offset 0x80(%rsp)
13996.730:006c:0078:trace:unwind:dump_unwind_info     0x11: leaq 0x80(%rsp),rbp
13996.730:006c:0078:trace:unwind:dump_unwind_info     0x9: subq $0x168,%rsp
13996.730:006c:0078:trace:unwind:dump_unwind_info     0x2: pushq %rbx
13996.730:006c:0078:trace:unwind:dump_unwind_info     0x1: pushq %rbp
13996.730:006c:0078:trace:seh:RtlRestoreContext returning to 00006FFFFF80D98A stack 0000000000A2DCA0
13996.730:006c:0078:trace:seh:dispatch_exception code=6ba flags=0 addr=00006FFFFFC1CF07 ip=6fffffc1cf07
13996.730:006c:0078:warn:seh:dispatch_exception RPC_S_SERVER_UNAVAILABLE exception (code=6ba) raised
13996.730:006c:0078:trace:seh:dispatch_exception  rax=0000000000a2d7e0 rbx=0000000000a2dac8 rcx=0000000000a2d7e0 rdx=0000000000000000
13996.730:006c:0078:trace:seh:dispatch_exception  rsi=00000000000000cc rdi=00000000007f5aa0 rbp=0000000000a2d8b0 rsp=0000000000a2d7c0

There's something going on with RPC, I guess, but I don't know where to start fixing it, if it is at all the problem?

My suggestion will probably require additional work in terms of dependency compatibility but have you already tried to build your app as a native executable for Linux?

Yes, that is actually the way I went. There were problems with the video codec then, but the game runs on the Steam Deck now (the videos are not super important): https://store.steampowered.com/app/2695130/Escape_Team/
